# Why would Visual Studio execute the dockerfile from the parent folder?

Tags: visual-studio, dockerfile

I am new to docker. I created an ASP.NET Core website with docker enabled, targeting Windows. The **.sln** file and **.dockerignore** file is in the root folder, while the website is in a "WebApplication1" subfolder.

The docker file generated by Visual Studio contains the following command:

```
COPY "WebApplication1/WebApplication1.csproj" .
```

This indicates to me that **when Visual Studio runs this docker file, it rans from the parent folder, not from the dockerfile's folder**. When I pressed F5 on Visual Studio, the container is built and run successfully.

However, if I open a CMD and navigate to the dockerfile's folder, and run the "**docker build**" command:

```
docker build -t webapplication1:v1 .
```

It complained at the COPY command that the files to be copied can't be found. It is obvious why, because I was running from within the dockerfile's folder, not the parent folder.

If I change the COPY command to the following:

```
COPY "WebApplication1.csproj" .
```

My "**docker build**" command succeeded, but "F5" on Visual Studio complained that the files to be copied do not exist.

**Why does Visual Studio execute the dockerfile from the parent folder? How to make Visual Studio and my CMD command both succeed?**